# How to process batch of elements in Flux in parallel environment

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, reactive, flux

In the below piece of code, I see an IDE error for buffer. I want to be able to group elements in to batch of three using buffer but it isn't working.

My goal is, divide flux into parallel rails, and each rail gets set amount of elements in a batch size. Could you help me achieve it?

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

public class BufferAndRunOnExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux.range(1, 10)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.parallel()) // Run the following operators on the parallel scheduler
                .doOnNext(number -> System.out.println("Processing element: " + number))
                .buffer(3) // Group elements into batches of size 3
                .doOnNext(batch -> System.out.println("Batch: " + batch))
                .sequential() // Merge the parallel streams back into a sequential stream
                .blockLast(); // Block and wait for the completion of the entire stream
    }
}
```

I tried reading Flux documentation
I tried searching for it on Bard, OpenAI but with no luck

Comment: May I ask why you need to do the buffering inside the parallel flux, not outside?

Comment: You can use `flatMap` to execute multiple queries concurrently. By default, `flatMap` will process `Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE = 256` number of in-flight inner sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but you simply need to move the buffer before the parallel call. Like this:

```java
    Flux.range(1, 10)
                .buffer(3)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .doOnNext(number -> {
                    sleepMillis(1000);
                    System.out.println(number + "Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                })
                .doOnNext(number -> {
                    sleepMillis(1000);
                    System.out.println("Processing element: " + number);
                })
                .doOnNext(batch -> {
                    sleepMillis(1000);
                    System.out.println("Batch: " + batch);
                })
                .sequential() 
                .blockLast();
```

By calling sleepMillis(1000) you will be able to see the parallel processing every step of the way.

In addition, by calling, Thread.currentThread().getName(), you can see the thread name which will confirm parallel processing.